# How to make TeamViewer auto-close sessions after idling for some time

Tags: teamviewer

Imagine a situation where I connect to my home computer with TV and forget to close the session. I come home and the session is still open so I can't do anything. Is there a way to make an idling session close?

Answer (score 0):

Teamviewer cannot do this unfortunately.  It may be worth putting in a feature request with the developers and see if it is something they feel is worth while implementing.

I've done a bit of searching and it has been suggested that if you set a screensaver with a password on your machine, that teamviewer may disconnect on the screen saver loading - but there are very mixed views as to wether this actually works or not... and it seems to vary by version.

Answer (score 0):

If you go to `Extras` - `Options` - `Advanced`. There is `Timing out inactive session` settings for connections to other computers.

If your situation is being connected from other computers, and you want to auto-close the sessions after idling for some time, then you may use a combination of Watch 4 Idle (http://www.addictivetips.com/windows-tips/set-pc-to-auto-shutdown-run-certain-program-when-idle/) and a batch script as below:

```
@echo off

REM Kill teamviewer
taskkill /f /im "TeamViewer.exe" >nul 
REM Wait 30 seconds to give your prgram time to close fully - (optional)
timeout /t 30 >null

REM Restart program, with title and program path
start "TeamViewer" "C:\Program Files (x86)\TeamViewer\TeamViewer.exe"
```